# matplotlib.pyplot.xticks - moves my plot data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

[image: Image with 2015 on X axis]

I have the above plot, which is almost perfect, but I want to get rid of the 2015, and I have to do it with code not paint.

When I try the following code;

```
    plt.xticks(np.arange(12), calendar.month_name[1:13], rotation=20)
```

My plot gets all messed up;

[image: Messed up image]

How can I use plt.xticks without it squishing all my plot data over to the right hand side?

Comment: You wouldn't use `xticks` at all. Instead use a formatter that does not have 2015 in it. If you want to share a [mcve], I'd be easier to know how you create the plot in the first place and hence what the best obtion here is.

Comment: Its for an online course so I don't want to post too much information. I've submitted my plot as-is, it should still get a good grade. The x-axis is DatetimeIndex